# SDL2 の開発(実行)環境に必要なコンポーネントがOSにインストール済みかを確認する方法は？

Tags: linux, macos, windows-10, sdl

windows10,MacOS,Linuxを対象にしたバイナリをSDL2を用いてwindwos10で制作しようと考えています。

http://sdl2referencejp.osdn.jp/Introduction.html に

> ### 1.3 SDLが使える環境は?
>
> #### Windows
>
> - 表示にWin32 APIとハードウェアアクセラレーションのためにDirect3Dを使用する
> - 音声にDirectSoundとXAudio2を使用する
>
> #### Mac OS X
>
> - 表示にCocoaとハードウェアアクセラレーションのためにOpenGLを使用する
> - 音声にCore Audioを使用する
>
> #### Linux
>
> - 表示にX11とハードウェアアクセラレーションのためにOpenGLを使用する
> - 音声にALSA, OSS, PulseAudio APIを使用する

と記述されているのですが。

現行のバージョンのwindows,Mac,Linuxで、インストール時にデフォルトで組み込まれていないものはありますでしょうか。
また、組み込まれている or いないの判別手段(コマンド等)ありましたらご教示お願いいたします。

Comment: 単に Windows を対象にしているなら、macOS や Linux の説明やタグは省いた方がシンプルになる気がします。

Comment: 質問の内容を編集させていただきました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

実行環境は以下のような感じになるようです。
Windows10, MacOS X はだいたい標準で入っているでしょう。
Linux系がインストール時の選択に依存するでしょうが、GUIを使うなら何かしらインストールするのでは？
なお開発用にはコンパイラ、SDK、フレームワークとかが必須だし、それらがインストールされているか等の確認方法は使うツールセットに依存するでしょう。

---

**Windows10**

- Win32API : OS標準API
- Direct3D : ハードウェアとデバイスドライバに依存するが、だいたいインストール済み。`dxdiag`コマンドで確認
- DirectSound : 下記XAudio2でエミュレーション
- XAudio2 : 標準搭載

[PC にインストールされている DirectX バージョンの確認](https://support.microsoft.com/ja-jp/help/15061/windows-which-version-directx)
[DirectSound - Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectSound) XAudio2も記載

---

**Mac OS X**

- Cocoa : OS標準機能
- OpenGL : 今までは標準でインストール済み。ただし1つ前の版から非推奨状態。
- Core Audio : OS標準機能

[About OS X App Design](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/MOSXAppProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)
[What Is Core Audio?](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/CoreAudioOverview/WhatisCoreAudio/WhatisCoreAudio.html)
[OpenGL および OpenCL グラフィックスを扱う Mac コンピュータ](https://support.apple.com/ja-jp/HT202823)
[Apple、macOS/iOSで「OpenGL/CL」の利用を“非推奨”に](https://pc.watch.impress.co.jp/docs/news/1125772.html)

---

**Linux**

- X11 : `xdpyinfo`コマンドで確認
- OpenGL : `glxinfo`コマンドで確認
- ALSA : `aplay -l`コマンドで確認
- OSS : `ossinfo`, `osstest`, `ossdetect -v`などのコマンドで確認
  ：現在ではあまり使われなくなっている模様。
- PulseAudio : `pactl list`コマンドで確認

[how to check linux X11 version?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17606442/9014308)
[What is terminal command that can show OpenGL version?](https://askubuntu.com/q/47062)
[Noob’s Guide to Linux Audio: ALSA, OSS, and Pulse Audio Explained](https://linuxhint.com/guide_linux_audio/)
[Open Sound System - ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.jp/index.php/Open_Sound_System)

---